# Equality of dynamically changing variable counts

Tags: python

I am a newbie in Python so I made a code that checks multiple long numbers and finds which digits of the numbers are common.

```
print('Counts:')
count = int(input())
print('Lengths:')
nm_len = int(input())
numbers = []
print('Input numbers:')
numbers = [int(input()) for i in range(count)]
print('Numbers stored!')
print(numbers)
for n in range(count):
    globals()['nm%s' % n] = [int(d) for d in str(numbers[n])]
print('Same numbers:')
for j in range(nm_len):
    if nm0[j] == nm1[j] == nm2[j]:
        print(j+1,'. number is same')
```

The program just works fine except for the last part which is the equality checking. With this code, it works if you input 3 for the counts at the first step but does not work if you but more or less than 3.

Is there any way to make the last `if` equality work dynamically? I mean if I input for example 5 for the counts at the first step, then the program will know it and makes the `if` just like `nm0[j] == nm1[j] == nm2[j] == nm3[j] == nm4[j]`.

Comment: Dynamically creating variables that way is an anti-pattern and non-pythonic. Instead you could just have `nm` be a list of lists and then do `nm[i][j]` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can start here.  It seems silly to ask for the number of digits, especially if you don't enforce that.  We just keep everything as a list.  Very general purpose.

```
count = int(input("How many: "))
print('Input numbers:')
numbers = [int(input()) for _ in range(count)]
print('Numbers stored!')
print(numbers)
nm = [str(n) for n in numbers]
print('Same digits:')
for i,x in enumerate(zip(*nm)):
    if all(x[0] == j for j in x):
        print('Digit', i+1,'is the same')
```

Don't use `globals()`.  Except in very specialized circumstances, it is never the right answer.